# Display custom Taxonomies same as listing Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories

I have used CPT UI plugin to create a custom post type and a custom taxonomy to go with it. In a manner as similar to `wp_list_categories()` as possible, I'd like to list these new custom taxonomies as a list of links that, when clicked, display the pages associated with the tags therein.

Comment: use `wp_list_categories` then?

Comment: @Milo Doing that will only list normal post categories. It will not list the custom taxonomies I created to serve as tags exclusively for this custom post type. That is, unless there is an argument I can add that filters these taxonomies. Based on Google searches, I am not finding anything that straight forward.

Comment: [Have you read the documentation?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) The argument you are looking for is `taxonomy`.

Comment: Using that exact code was my first attempt, prior to resorting to fruitless Google searches. Using the slug/name of my custom taxonomy in place of 'category' produces nothing.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by renaming the custom taxonomy. I was unaware that having a "-" in the name would interfere with using it as an argument within wp_list_categories().